# PHP validation fails when executing on another computer, but same browser, same script, same server, same permissions

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have lost many nights of sleep because of this. Any help is very much appreciated.

There is a very simple validation in my .php file, which checks for the **file extension**, after the user uploads a file through a form.

```
    $allowed =  array('png','jpg','rar','zip');
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed)) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= 'File is not of type png, jpg, rar or zip';
        $validData = false;
    }
```

**When I access the page of the form and submit a file, the form works as it should.** It throws error if I don't upload a file with the correct extension, and success otherwise.

**But when anybody else, from another computer, submits a file in the form, it ALWAYS throws error.** I cannot understand what is happening.

As I have mentioned in the question title, the server, browser, script are all the same. *And the rest of the form (name, faculty, facebook link etc) transfers correctly, no errors!*

Note: the environment is live.

Comment: Can you explain the error message? And which file one is going to upload so you are getting an error?

Comment: in local or live environment? If it is local check PATHINFO_EXTENSION (acceptpathinfo is on in apache) is installed in other computers. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

Comment: @KinjalMistry Any type of file. If it is png, jpg, rar, zip it will return error, even though the validation is pretty straightforward. Right now the environment is live, and I cannot get a more explicit error from users. I will be using another computer and throw a more detailed one.

Comment: @ManigandanArjunan It is live environment.

Comment: @romaniucradu Can you please tell us what exception you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Use explode to Fetch the file extension
 Try this:

```
$name= $_FILES['file']['make'];
$ext = explode('.',$name);
$fileExt= end($ext);
```

Now you can check if `$fileExt` is in the allowed extension array

```
if (in_array($fileExt, $allowed))
```

This should get the job done irrespective of the machine